# How to hide select option with z-index?

Tags: html, css

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmgeg21u/8/).

As you can see the `select` is postioned behind once you hover one of the options to reveal more panels however if `select` is clicked upon to reveal `option` and then the mouse hovers again over panels, the `select`remains positioned behind properly however `option` is in front. I've been trying to cover it with `z-index` but it doesn't work, or I'm having a problem somewhere else. Is there a way to fix that with `z-index`?

Snippet as well:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
option {
    z-index: -1;
}
nav {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C2082F;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
textarea {
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    right: 160%;
}

ul ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 0%;
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #C2082F;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}

ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

ul li:hover { background-color: gray; }

ul li a:hover { background-color: gray; }
span.dropBottom, span.dropRight {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px  black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

span.dropBottom {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#note {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 45%;
    width: 17%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:black;
}
#version {
    font-style: italic;
    color:black;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:90%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#format {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <div style='width:100px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px' >
                Sinistri
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> 
                        Inserimento sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca sinistro
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Rapporti sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li style='width: 250px;'>
            <a href="#">
                Assicurazioni
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                        Polizze gruppo
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="#">
                        Veicoli
                    </a>
                    <span class="dropRight">
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Inserimento veicoli
                            </a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Ricerca veicoli
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px;'>
                Contratti
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Inserimento contratti
                    </a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca contratti
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div style="width:400px; display: inline-block;"></div>
<select>
<option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry for a lot of `z-index`es in the code, i've been trying to put them in various places to see if one of them will work eventually.

Comment: The <select> element is an interactive content element in HTML5 and a menu in HTML4.01. As such it is an object which requires user input and behaves like a right click context menu and is rendered above all document elements if active. Try it for yourself - open your contextmenu and hover over the navigation.

This bug is connected to the behavior of other interactive content elements such as video (see also HTML5 rendering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**Method 1:**

Put select in a div  and apply a rule that when ever you hover over nav the focus of select should disappear.

```
nav:hover ~ .selecthack > select:focus{
    display:none;    
}
```

**Method 2:** Use some jQuery

1. First add link of jQuery library just before  :
2. Now add this code before  tag:

   $(function() {
         $('nav').hover(function() {
           $('select').blur();
         })
       })

```js
$(function() {
  $('nav').hover(function() {
    $('select').blur();
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #C2082F;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  right: 160%;
}

ul ul li:hover>ul {
  top: 0%;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #C2082F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul ul li {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

span.dropBottom,
span.dropRight {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}

span.dropBottom {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#note {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 45%;
  width: 17%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

#version {
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 90%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#format {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  color: black;
}

#Title {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

#TopPanel {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C2082F;
  width: 1889px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#buttons {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px gray outset;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#buttons:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#ButtonsTable {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px gray outset;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#ButtonsTable:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#ButtonsTable:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Trova1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.TrovaSelect {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.TrovaSelect:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

#SmallButton {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border: 2px gray outset;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#SmallButton:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#afix {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

.selecthack {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div style='width:400px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style='width: 250px'>
                Sinistri
            </a>
      <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> 
                        Inserimento sinistri
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                        Ricerca sinistro
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                        Rapporti sinistri
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <div style='width:100px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
    <li style='width: 250px;'>
      <a href="#">
                Assicurazioni
            </a>
      <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
                        Polizze gruppo
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                        Veicoli
                    </a>
          <span class="dropRight">
                    </span>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                                Inserimento veicoli
                            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                                Ricerca veicoli
                            </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <div style='width:100px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style='width: 250px;'>
                Contratti
            </a>
      <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                        Inserimento contratti
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                        Ricerca contratti
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<?php
include_once '/Main/FunctionsBar.php'
?>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width: 800px;"></div>
  <div id="Title" style="display:inline-block;">Ricerca sinistri</div>
  <div id='TopPanel'>
    <span id='Trova1' style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
        Trova per luogo
    </span>
    <div class="selecthack">
      <select class='TrovaSelect'>
            <option hidden></option>
            <option value='Lugano'>
                Lugano
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span id='Trova1' style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
        Trova no. Pratica
    </span>
    <select class='TrovaSelect'>
        <option hidden></option>
        <option value='1'>
            1
        </option>
    </select>
    <span style="margin-left:100px;"></span>
    <a href="http://sinistri.ecsa.ch/MainPanel.php?pagina=/Sinistri/TopPanel.php&pagina2=/Sinistri/RicercaSinistro.php">
      <button id="ButtonsTable">
            Pannelli
        </button>
    </a>
    <span style="margin-left: 50px;"></span>
    <a href="http://sinistri.ecsa.ch/MainPanel.php?pagina=/Sinistri/TopPanel.php&pagina2=/Sinistri/InterrogazioneIncidentiLuogoOAutore.php">
      <button id="ButtonsTable">
            Tabelle
        </button>
    </a>
    <span style="margin-left: 50px;"></span>
    <a href="http://sinistri.ecsa.ch/Sinistri/PDFphp/SegnalazioneIncidenti-PDF.php">
      <button id="ButtonsTable" style="width: 130px;">
            Sinistri pdf
        </button>
    </a>
    <br>
    <span id='Trova1' style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
        Trova per data
    </span>
    <select class='TrovaSelect'>
        <option hidden></option>
        <option value='23.07.2016'>
            23.07.2016
        </option>
    </select>
    <br> <br>
  </div>
  <div id="format">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "InterrogazioneIncidentiLuogoOAutore") {
        include('InterrogazioneIncidentiLuogoOAutore.php');
    }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: The <select> element is an interactive content element in HTML5 and a menu in HTML4.01. As such it is an object which requires user input and behaves like a right click context menu and is rendered above all document elements if active. I don't think there is any other way to change this behavior using CSS. Maybe javascript can be used.

Comment: In your snippet the method works perfectly and would be useful to me, however once I tried to apply your solution to my main file it didn't work. Not sure why. Specifically `nav:hover~.selecthack>select:focus {
  display: none;
}` this part doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I tried with one of the selects I have that creates an issue, added `inline-block` to it becuase it was needed so the class works, but the part I mentioned earlier doesn't.

Comment: [Here's bigger part of my main file](https://jsfiddle.net/rtqre9pf/1/), as you can see if you choose the first one where I applied your hack, it doesn't works. It's possible some other code interferes? or maybe it's becuase I'm using PHP? @RobertWilliams

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149083/discussion-between-robert-williams-and-zabusy).

Answer (score 1):

> Just enough remove `focus` of `select` element when `li` get hover.So for remove focus use of `blur` funcion.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul:first-child > li').hover(function(){
    $('select').blur();
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul:first-child > li').hover(function(){
    $('select').blur();
  })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
select {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
option {
    z-index: -1;
}
nav {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C2082F;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
textarea {
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    right: 160%;
}

ul ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 0%;
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #C2082F;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}

ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

ul li:hover { background-color: gray; }

ul li a:hover { background-color: gray; }
span.dropBottom, span.dropRight {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px  black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

span.dropBottom {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#note {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 45%;
    width: 17%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:black;
}
#version {
    font-style: italic;
    color:black;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:90%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#format {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <div style='width:100px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px' >
                Sinistri
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> 
                        Inserimento sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca sinistro
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Rapporti sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li style='width: 250px;'>
            <a href="#">
                Assicurazioni
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                        Polizze gruppo
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="#">
                        Veicoli
                    </a>
                    <span class="dropRight">
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Inserimento veicoli
                            </a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Ricerca veicoli
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px;'>
                Contratti
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Inserimento contratti
                    </a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca contratti
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div style="width:400px; display: inline-block;"></div>
<select>
<option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While that's a creative way of doing it, in my main file sliding `select` left and right is not a good option, I simply need the `ul li` to be positioned infront of everything, that way `option` is hidden behind it.

Comment: That's perfect, I tried to apply it with my main code it didn't work however. I think it's becuase the nav bar and what's below in my main code are two separate pages connected with PHP.

Comment: I marked it as useful becuase it works in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Remove **z-index: 9999;** from

```
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 25px;
 background-color: #C2082F;
 cursor: pointer;  
}
```

add **z-index: 9999;** to

```
ul li:hover > ul {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 100%;
 visibility: visible;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

Try Following code:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
option {
    z-index: -1;
}
nav {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C2082F;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
textarea {
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    right: 160%;
}

ul ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 0%;
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 9999;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #C2082F;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

ul li:hover { background-color: gray; }

ul li a:hover { background-color: gray; }
span.dropBottom, span.dropRight {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px  black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

span.dropBottom {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#note {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 45%;
    width: 17%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:black;
}
#version {
    font-style: italic;
    color:black;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:90%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#format {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <div style='width:100px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px' >
                Sinistri
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> 
                        Inserimento sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca sinistro
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Rapporti sinistri
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li style='width: 250px;'>
            <a href="#">
                Assicurazioni
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                        Polizze gruppo
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="#">
                        Veicoli
                    </a>
                    <span class="dropRight">
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Inserimento veicoli
                            </a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Ricerca veicoli
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div style='width:20px; display:inline-block; min-height: 1px;'></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style='width: 250px;'>
                Contratti
            </a>
            <span class="dropBottom">
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Inserimento contratti
                    </a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        Ricerca contratti
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div style="width:400px; display: inline-block;"></div>
<select>
<option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This didn't change anything though. "Hello world" is still visible if you click on select as an option when hobering over other elements that should be infront.